# How can set Kendo Date Picker Min value Programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Kendo Date picker in my view I also have a dropdown, I need help to set date picker min value programmatically. When type dropdown value changes I would like to restrict data picker as if type.text= x, set minValue = currentYear - 1, when type.text = y set minValue = currentYear - 2.

I have a type dropdown

```
<input id="type" />
<script>

$("#type").kendoDropDownList({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "x" },
    { id: 2, name: "y" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id"
});
</script>
```

I have Fiscal year DatePicker as:

```
 @(
    Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("Fiscal Year"))
    .Format("{0:yyyy}")
    .Depth(CalendarView.Decade)
    .Start(CalendarView.Decade)                       
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
  )
```

I like to apply the folloding condition

```
    if Type = x then minValue = currentYear-1
    if Type = y then minValue = currentYear-2
    else display as is
```

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/methods/setoptions